# Importance of Axioms of Choice in Applied Mathematics

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question, axiom-of-choice

I’m not professional and know some calculus and linear algebra.

My intuition is that AC dones't seem to be necessary for applied mathematics.

Is AC important in applied mathematics? For example, does it help in developing numerical methods?

Comment: I agree that it is not necessary for applied mathematics.

Comment: A whole lot of the theory necessary in applications requires the AoC, have a look at the answer by Joel David Hamkins here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20882/most-unintuitive-application-of-the-axiom-of-choice